# BootstrapVueでサンプル(特にb-form-select)がうまく表示できない。

Tags: node.js, vue.js, form, twitter-bootstrap

[BootstrapVueのサイト](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#complete-example)にある"Complete example"のサンプルを利用したいのですがうまく表示されません。
特にソート・フィルターなどの表以外の部分でサンプルの表示と異なります。
どうやらb-form-selectが上手く表示されていないようなので[そちらのサンプル](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#comp-ref-b-form-select)も試しましたがやはりサンプルと同じように表示されません。

以下作業内容とソースになります。間違っていそうなところがないかご確認いただけないでしょうか？

1. パッケージの作成

   `vue create paging-table`
   ※Vue2を選択しております。
2. パッケージのインストール

   `npm install bootstrap bootstrap-vue`
3. パッケージの内容

```js
    {
      "name": "paging-table",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "serve:backend": "node ./src/server.js",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.22.0",
        "core-js": "^3.8.3",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.4.1",
        "sass": "^1.32.7",
        "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
      }
    }
```

4. main.jsの編集

```js
    import Vue from "vue";
    import App from "./App.vue";
    import router from "./router";
    import store from "./store";
    
    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
    
    import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from "bootstrap-vue";
    
    // Import Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
    import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
    import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
    
    // Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
    Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
    // Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
    Vue.use(IconsPlugin);
    
    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount("#app");
```

5. AboutView.vueの編集
   [BootstrapVueのサイト](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#complete-example)のサンプルをそのままコピペしました。

Answer (score 1):

ごめんなさい。解決いたしました。

BootstrapVueの公式サイトにあるサンプルは編集が可能です。で、ここで自分のコードをコピペしてみたのですが当然上手く表示されるわけです（そもそもサンプルをコピペしているので）。

そこで改めて[Getting Started](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs)に立ち直ってみたところ、初っ端のメジャーバージョンが4になっていました。
さて、皆様お気づきだと思いますがpackeage.jsonを見てみると5になっています。
そこでサイトのバージョンに合わせるとサンプルと同様に表示されました。安心しました。

くだらない質問になってしまい申し訳ございません。